# Configurar campo timestamp para aceitar valor 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Estou com erro no `postgres`, porque um campo que é `timestamp` esta recebendo valor '0000-00-00 00:00:00', sabem me dizer como configuro um campo `timestamp` aceitar data e hora zerados ?

Segue erro:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  LINE 120: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom - essa aí não é uma timestamp válida, não é? Não existe ano 0 no nosso calendário - é 1A.C e e em seguida, ano 1 D.C. - as representações de data e hora nesse formato nnão dão conta dessas datas.

A documentação do PostgreSQL diz que ele deve se comportar bem com datas "antes de cristo", mas o formato de string para timestamps "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"  não permite isso. Não chequei a docuemntação para verificar se timestamp podem ter anos "antes de cristo" ou se isso é limitado para os tipos "data".

De qualquer forma, o menor timestamp possível no postgres é 1 de janeiro do ano 1 D.C., 00:00:00 - e você pode inserir esse valor no banco usando a string `'-infinity'` na sua query. (Mas `'0001-01-01 00:00:00'` também vai funcionar).

Claro que datas são estranhas quando você passa alguns limites em que houve mudança de calendário - então o melhor mesmo talvez seja construir sua aplicação considerando como "timestamp 0" um limite mais próximo.

Todos os sistemas Unix - Linux e MacOS inclusive, começam a contagem interna em 1970-1-1 , por exemplo, e essa pode ser uma boa data para você considerar como "0". Outros sistemas consideram como "data 0", 1900-1-1 - fica a critério do que fizer mais sentido aí.

## O que fazer se você não tem controle sobre os dados que chegam

Pela sua pergunta, você dá a entender que o seu banco está recebendo esses valores e você não tem como mudar isso.

Bom, pelos motivos de "ano zero não existe no calendário gregoriano", não tem como configurar o PostgreSQL para aceitar  `0000-00-00` como uma data válida, não importa o que você faça.
Acredito que o caminho nesse caso é: criar uma outra coluna do tipo datetime, que será a coluna com a data efetivamente, que suas aplicações vão consumir e atualizar. Transformar a coluna atual onde chegam as timestamps com defeito numa coluna de texto (char) - e criar um *trigger* para, a cada inserção nessa coluna, copiar o valor pra coluna "real" se for um timestamp válido, ou, se for inválido (como o "0"), inserir um valor padrão (uma das sugestões acima para valor "0"). Isso pelo menos temporariamente até quem quer que envie os dados para você poder corrigir do lado dele, e não enviar um valor inválido.

Comment: Bom dia, Ajustei a pergunta, estou recebendo o valor: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: A resposta continua a mesma. A sugestão do que você fazer está no último parágrafo. Dependendo da aplicação que for consumir os dados, você pode converter esse "pseudo" time-stamp  para data e hora na aplicação, em vez de ter um trigger dentro do banco para replicar os valores para uma  uma coluna de timestamp real. Nesse caso, você configura a coluna como texto na sua aplicação, e, ao ler os dados dessa coluna, coloca uma logica customizada para tratar o valor com ano = 0000